# SLES 12.3 and oracleasm module issue

Tags: kernel-modules, sles, oracle

So...
Fresh installation of Sles 12.3, kernel 4.4.73-5-default, x64, Oracle support packages installed using zypper from official SUSE repositories...

```
~:rpm -qa | grep orac
oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.SLE12.x86_64
oracleasmlib-2.0.12-1.SLE12.x86_64
oracleasm-kmp-default-2.0.8_k4.4.73_5-2.35.x86_64
```

But I was unable to modprobe oracleasm module

```
# modprobe oracleasm
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'oracleasm': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

When I checked `dmesg`

```
[183106.200221] oracleasm: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[183106.200692] oracleasm: Unknown symbol bio_unmap_user (err 0)
[184399.043815] oracleasm: Unknown symbol bio_unmap_user (err 0)
[184544.509230] oracleasm: Unknown symbol bio_unmap_user (err 0)
[184698.192950] oracleasm: Unknown symbol bio_unmap_user (err 0)
```

This was working on Sles 12.2.

Reinstall to Sles 12.2 or ...?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: install SLES 12.1. Version above that simply do not work with oracleasm

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by non-export of bio_unmap_user kernel function in updated SUSE kernel. There is oracleasm update available to fix this issue on SLES12 SP3:
oracleasm-kmp-default-2.0.8_k4.4.92_6.18-3.6.1.x86_64.rpm

https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=fAshWD23NFc~

Comment: Still not working...